# TreeViewItem-Image depending on children

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have the following style for my `TreeView`:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Width="16" Height="16"/>
                     <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `TreeView` is defined as:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Pages">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Google"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Stackoverflow"/>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Stuff">
        <TreeViewItem Header="MyDomain"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Other Domains">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Domain 1"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Domain 2"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Domain 3"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Now I want to set the Image in the `HeaderTemplate`. If the `TreeViewItem` has childnodes, I want a different Image than if it hasn't any children.

The Images are located in a static class as `ImageSources`. If I type:

```
<Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{x:Static helper:ImageHelper.TreeFolder}"/>
```

It just works fine. But than all `TreeViewItems` have the same Image.

So I thought about writing a converter and use this as source like:

```
<Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource treeImageConverter}"/>
```

My problem now is: How can I detect in my converter if the current `TreeViewItem` has children? I've tried to pass it as ConverterParameter but I don't know how to set this correctly in the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to assign a `Style` to `Image` control with `DataTrigger` which checks `TreeViewItem.HasItems` property:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="ImageForTreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Static helper:ImageHelper.Image1}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Static helper:ImageHelper.Image2}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```